# Why does the <img> source path works only for import and url?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, reactjs

I am trying to create a simple react site. But in the process of creating it, I have encountered this issue with `<img src="./logo.png"></img>`.

**Situation**

- Image loads normally when I use image URL or I use `import LOGO from "./logo.png"`
  But when I use `<img src="./logo.png" alt=sample-image></img>`, my image doesn't load and alt text appears.

Please help to understand why is it happening.
Here is my full code of JS file-

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client"
import LOGO from "./logo.png"
const divElement = (
    <div>
        <img src={LOGO} alt="react-logo" width="40px"></img>
        <h1>Fun Facts About React</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Was first released in 2013</li>
            <li>Was originally created by Jordan Walke</li>
            <li>Has well over 100K stars on Github</li>
            <li>Is maintained by Facebook</li>
            <li>Powers thousands of enterprise apps, including mobile apps</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
)
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(divElement)
```

Comment: not an expert but I assume you are using webpack and it has something to do with the way webpack is configured

Comment: me neither. Currently using the files that I got during the default react app creation process, only deleted all files from src folder and using my own HTML, JS files.

Comment: This ensures that when the project is built, webpack will correctly move the images into the build folder, and provide us with correct paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created the project with vite or CRA, you need to put your image in the public folder and then your path would be :

```js
<img src="/logo.png" alt="sample-image" />
```

Comment: Great! Keeping the image in the public folder has worked. But I am still wondering why `<img src="./logo.png"></img>` doesn't work in the src folder when it works for the import technique.